# Удаление директории

Tags: c#, файлы

Пытаюсь удалить папку, содержащую файлы ( в моём случае png)

```
Directory.Delete("Pictures");
```

Вылезает исключение,которое сообщает, что папка не пуста и удаление невозможно. Каким образом я могу избавиться от этой директории, не прибегая к удалению всех файлов, которые она содержит?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Directory.Delete("Pictures", true);
```